# TOM.NET API - create Session in custom Translation Manager event handler

Tags: web8.5, tom.net, translation-manager

I'm using a custom event handler to generate an email when the status of Translation Jobs changes to *InTranslation* and *Completed*.

```
EventSystem.SubscribeAsync<ITranslationJob, ITranslationJobStateChangeEventArgs>(OnTranslationJobStateChange, EventPhases.Initiated, EventSubscriptionOrder.Early);
```

When the status is *InTranslation* I'm able to access the **AddedItems** property and include TCM & Title of the items from the translation job in my email. Usually bundles are sent to translation so its the bundle TCM & Title.

When the status is *Completed*, the **AddedItems** property is empty and I use **TmsTranslationJobs.TargetItems** to try and generate a list of it TCMs & titles of items that gave completed translated.

```
var targets = translationJob.TmsTranslationJobs.SelectMany(t => t.TargetItems);
```

If a bundle was sent originally, **TmsTranslationJobs.TargetItems** is actually the Component TCMs inside the bundle.

For some reason the API for **TargetItems** only contains the TCM (via the **SourceUri** property) of the Components inside a bundle, not titles.

[image]

I thought I could use this TCM to load the Component via the TOM.NET API and get its title but the TOM.NET API requires a Session object to be passed to every Component constructor but I'm not sure how to construct that Session object - as I haven't subscribed to a Content Manager object I have no access to a Session?

I see in the Session class it can be instantiated with a username:

```
var s = new Session(string userName);
```

Is it *safe* to get a Session this way?

Cheers

Comment: Have you considered getting the title from the tcm Id using the Core Services API instead of the TOM API? You could just create a .NET Web method that will  create the CoreService instance and  return the title of the component TCMID you pass to it.

Comment: I had, but it seems unnecessary to use the Core Service from within the context of an event handler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two things you can do.

**First**

If it is sufficient or preferable for you to get **AddedItems** during **complete** event

They are available but not loaded.

Use ITranslationJob.**LoadState** property to see what data loaded in translation job

And then if AddedItems is not loaded

Use  ITranslationJob.**LoadDetails** (TranslationJobLoadFilters.**AddedItems**) to load them.

**Second**

You can get always to **TOM.NET Session** by casting **subject** of event (e.g ITranslationJob or ITranslationConfiguration) to Tridion.ContentManager.**IdentifiableObject** and get current session from Session property.

Good luck

Comment: Great answer Yuri - many thanks. For our purposes I opted for the LoadState/LoadDetails approach.

Answer (score 3):

I've read somewhere (on multiple occasions) that when in TOM.NET you should never initiate the `Session` object on your own, rather you should reuse the existing one. For example in Templating this is done with the `engine.GetSession()`, in Event handlers the subject of the event has a `Session` property, etc.

But looking at the Translation Manger API I see no way on how to acquire a "regular" `session`. Instead, it's the other way around where the `session` is used to create an `ITmSession`. (Do note that I'm not 100% certain of this, I could be mistaken, haven't worked with the Translation API that much).

Having all this said, I must also mention that I have seen `Session` objects initiated "by hand" and the code did work.

So to summarize, you **can** initiate the `Session`, but if there is another way, you should definitely take that route. Initiating the `Session` by hand is not recommended.

Comment: See my response on how to get to session in TM event handler (Just FYI for future)